# Why does @FetchRequest not update and redraw Views on Deletion?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data

**Context**

I have a pretty basic SwiftUI setup containing of a `ListView` presenting all Entities and a `DetailView` presenting just a single of these Entities. The `DetailView` also has a Delete option.

The problem I have is, that when deleting the Entity, SwiftUI does not navigate back to the `ListView`, even though the `@FetchRequest` should update and redraw the View including ChildViews. Instead, it keeps presenting the `DetailView` but since it deleted the Entity, it only presents the custom-implemented Default ("N/A") Value for its name.

---

**Code**

```swift
struct ListView: View {
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var entities: FetchedResults<Entity>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ForEach(entities) { entity in
                RowView(entity: entity)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RowView: View {
    @ObservedObject var entity: Entity

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(entity: entity)) {
            Text(entity.name)
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var context
    @ObservedObject var entity: Entity
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(entity.name)
            
            Button(action: { delete() }) { Text("Delete") }
        }
    }

    private func delete() {
        context.delete(entity)
        
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

- Why does SwiftUI not navigate back to the `ListView` on Deletion even though the `@FetchRequest` should update? How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FetchRequest does update, but the navigation link isn't dependent upon the parent's fetch request - it's not like a `sheet` or `fullScreenCover` where the `isPresented` or `item` bound attributes determine the new view's visibility.

The easiest thing to do is to handle the dismissal yourself using the `dismiss` environment function:

```swift
struct DetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var context

    // ...

    private func delete() {
        dismiss()
        context.delete(entity)
        // ...
    }
}
```

While `dismiss()` is more commonly seen with modals like sheets and full screen covers, it also works in navigation stacks to pop the current view off the stack.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this makes sense. However, is there a possibility to make the NavigationLink dependent on the FetchRequest to eliminate the need of manually dismissing Views on deletion?

Comment: Not easily. NavigationLink doesn't use object bindings in the same way that, say, the `.sheet()` modifier does. You could possibly monitor some of the notifications that the CoreData subsystem sends out, like `NSInvalidatedObjectsKey`, and manually filter the deleted objects out of your navigation path (if you're using the iOS16 `NavigationStack` API) - but it's honestly just easier to include `dismiss()`